# Getting items of FormArray with formControl but with a custom loop

Tags: angular

I have some dynamic input fields and I want to add them to my form group.

This is what I already have:

```html
<div class="services" *ngFor="let section of sections">
  <p>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Title of Section</mat-label>
      <input id="title-of-section-' + section" #titleOfSection matInput type="text" value="Section 1" placeholder="E.g. Basic Package"  [formControlName]="'title-of-section-' + section">
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>
  ...
```

```js
formMain = this.fb.group({
});
```

```js
this.formMain.addControl(`title-of-section-${amountOfServices}`, new FormControl(''));
```

`amountOfServices` is a increased number. So the controls could be:

- title-of-section-0
- title-of-section-1
- title-of-section-2

Well, that works fine but instead of that, I would like to have them all in an array, using `FormArray`.

So I changed my code to this:

```js
formMain = this.fb.group({
  titleOfSection: new FormArray([])
});
```

```js
const titleOfSection = this.formMain.get('titleOfSection') as FormArray;
titleOfSection.push(new FormControl());
```

That works fine as well. So now I have an array. But my problem is the HTML. I know that I could do something like this:

```html
<div formArrayName="titleOfSection">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of getItems().controls">
    <input type="text" [formControl]="$any(field)" value="foo">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

```js
getItems(): FormArray {
  return this.formMain.get('titleOfSection') as FormArray;
}
```

The reason why I don't want it that way, is because I need my current loop (see code above), which is `*ngFor="let section of sections"` since I need `section` also for the rest of my code.

So my question is, can I keep my current `for` loop but change `[formControlName]="'title-of-section-' + section"` to something like `[formControl]="'titleOfSection[section]"`?

The value of `sections` is the same as `titleOfSection.value.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason why I don't want it that way, is because I need my current
> loop (see code above), which is *ngFor="let section of sections" since
> I need section also for the rest of my code.

In this case you could keep this code:

```
<div formArrayName="titleOfSection">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of getItems().controls">
    <input type="text" [formControl]="$any(field)" value="foo">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Remove your `*ngFor="let section of sections"` and use the above instead. And when you want to access the `section` object you could do `field.value`.

If that is not to your liking, you could do:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of getItems().controls; index as i">
   {{ sections[i].something }}
</ng-container>
```

Since the indices in the `FormArray` correspond to the ones in the `sections` array, you could capture that by using `let index = i` in the `*ngFor` of the FormArray controls.

Comment: Thank you. I like the idea with the index. However, it did not work for me, so I had to replace `let index = i` with `index as i`. This now works with Angular version 5+.

Comment: To mannage a FormArray of FormControls it's suggested use `;let i=index` and `[formControlName]="i"` instead `[formControl]=$any(field)`

Comment: @Eliseo what is the difference?

Comment: @xRay, When you use the variable in for, Angular only know that is an abstractControl (it's the reason to use this "$any"). In Angular 2,3,4,5,6 and 7 you could make without use the "$any". The use of [formControlName]="i" always work. Really I don't know how "transpile" to javascript, so it's only a "personal opinion": I'm used to seeing it that way